# SQL: Joining 3 tables to generate report dashboard

Tags: mysql

I am trying to join 3 different tables that holds my test execution results as "PASS", "FAIL" and "SKIP". There are 2 common properties in these 3 tables on the basis of which I need to club my result i.e. "BUILD_NUMBER" and "COMPONENT".

Tried several approach but does not get the desired result.

[image]

Sample query:

```
select test_execution.COMPONENT, test_execution.BUILD_NUMBER, 
count(test_execution.TEST_STATUS) as PASS from (test_execution 
INNER JOIN test_execution_fail ON
test_execution.BUILD_NUMBER = test_execution_fail.BUILD_NUMBER) group by 
COMPONENT,BUILD_NUMBER;
```

My tables look like below:

```
CREATE TABLE test_execution_skip (
BUILD_NUMBER int,
TEST_NAME varchar(255),
TEST_CLASS varchar(255),
COMPONENT varchar(255),
TEST_STATUS varchar(255)
);
```

Other two tables are exactly same with test_execution and test_execution_fail as their names.

test_execution table holds 3 records(all pass values), test_execution_fail table holds 2 records (all fail values) and test_execution_skip table holds 1 record(skip value).

I want to populate data that will show me BUILD_NUMBER, COMPONENT, TOTAL, PASS, FAIL, SKIP as records where TOTAL, PASS, FAIL and SKIP will show the respectives counts.

Any help is appreciated here.

Comment: Can you provide some data?

Comment: Yes @AnthonyGenovese Please tell me what more info. you require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we see another instance of the "Table-per-*Thing*" Data Model and, once again, we see how it *causes* more problems than it *solves*.

Use *one* table - `test_execution` - and add a `result` column to it.
With proper indexing, you should have *no* performance issues.

Based on this one table, your query becomes [almost] trivial:

```
select 
  build_number
, component 
, sum( case when result = 'PASS' then 1 else 0 end ) passes 
, sum( case when result = 'FAIL' then 1 else 0 end ) fails 
, sum( case when result = 'SKIP' then 1 else 0 end ) skips 
from text_execution 
group by 
  build_number
, component 
order by 
  build_number
, component 
;
```

(Edit: Explanatory notes, as requested)

Given this data to start with:

```
select * 
from test_execution ; 

| component       | build_number | result | 
| Edge_Management |            1 | PASS   |
| Edge_Management |            1 | FAIL   |
| Edge_Management |            2 | PASS   |
| Edge_Management |            2 | SKIP   |
| Edge_Management |            2 | PASS   |
| Edge_Management |            3 | FAIL   |
```

The `case` clauses are the SQL equivalent of programming's IF..THENs.
They calculate values on the fly, without storing them anywhere, here converting the textual `result` field into individual elements that we can add up:

```
select 
  build_number
, component 
, result 
, sum( case when result = 'PASS' then 1 else 0 end ) passes 
, sum( case when result = 'FAIL' then 1 else 0 end ) fails 
, sum( case when result = 'SKIP' then 1 else 0 end ) skips 
from text_execution ; 

| component       | build_number | result | passes | fails | skips | 
| Edge_Management |            1 | PASS   |      1 |     0 |     0 |
| Edge_Management |            1 | FAIL   |      0 |     1 |     0 |
| Edge_Management |            2 | PASS   |      1 |     0 |     0 |
| Edge_Management |            2 | SKIP   |      0 |     0 |     1 |
| Edge_Management |            2 | PASS   |      2 |     0 |     0 |
| Edge_Management |            3 | FAIL   |      0 |     1 |     0 |
```

Then, the SUM() function and "GROUP BY" clauses work together to produce totals of each different result, as above.

Comment: Works like a charm. This seems something new to me. It would be great if you can add some more explanation to this approach?